# Slow wifi-connection

Tags: networking, wireless, virtualbox

My home setup is the following: at my router, there is a (wired) NAS. All other traffic is going via wifi. My laptop uses wifi to connect to the router, be it for going online (internet) or accessing the files on the NAS.

**Currently, I'm noticing some slowdowns in the connection (laptop to router) that I'm asking help with finding the cause of. Is there any locations I can look for log files, or do some diagnostics?**

Additional information:

- Because the laptop is new, I assume that's where the problem is. Corroborating evidence:

  - As it's not only internet but also accessing the NAS - right now I'm copying some files and it's been 1h to copy less than 2 GB from it - I can't be my ISP's fault.
  - Running a speedtest from the NAS (using https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/blob/master/speedtest_cli.py) gives a high internet-access-speed
  - Running a speedtest from the laptop (speedtest.net) gives a much lower speed (about 20% of that with which the NAS accesses the internet). This is while also copying files over from the NAS, though.
- A NAS share is mounted onto the laptop's filesystem with nfs. It's from here that I try to copy the files.
- Apart from the laptop and my smartphone, there no other devices using the router's wifi.
- I was running a (Windows) VM on the laptop before, at which point the file system on the NAS was almost impossibly slow to access through either the host or the guest (the guest has access via the 'shared folders' functionality of VirtualBox). Accessing the NAS has not gotten much faster (if at all) since shutting down the VM, but I thought I'd mention the VM as it appears to be when the performance started to drop.
- Not sure if related: System Monitor shows RAM usage of 5.6 (of 7.7) GB, but if I look at the processes, they don't add up to nearly that much. Firefox is using 1.1 GB, then Dropbox with 200 MB, and the next-biggest is <100 MB. I'm the only user on the system.

Comment: ***Not sure if related: System Monitor shows RAM usage of 5.6 (of 7.7) GB,*** The kernel borrows extra RAM for cache (think ram disk) and buffers but gives it back if needed by applications.

Comment: Use `tracepath` (`sudo apt install tracepath`) to determine the maximum MTU of your connection, then set your MTU to that number. An MTU of 1500 over WiFi causes packet fragmentation (which doubles the number of packets, halves the apparent  speed)

Answer (score 1):

You should try [iperf](https://iperf.fr/) if you can access to your NAS via shell or bash. That program tests the network speed among two peers.

You can also check the wifi configuration in your router. It is recommended that you use the N standard. In SOHO the wifi comes configured as mixed (b/g/n) wich causes low performance on the wifi connection.

Also, if u have any torrent program, try lowering the number of connections.

Hope it helps.